# Comprobar si campo "serial" está duplicado con un "if" en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Realizo un formulario en el cual inserto los datos de los equipos de cómputo (Sistema de Inventario).

Pero el problema que tengo es que mi sistema necesita una validación con un **if** para avisarme cuando se estén o intenten duplicar registros por el campo `serial`. Es decir, si ya existe ese registro con ese campo `serial` en mi base de datos.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");


     if (isset($_POST['serial']) && !empty($_POST['serial']) &&
        (isset($_POST['marca']) && !empty($_POST['marca'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['modelo']) && !empty($_POST['modelo'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['caracteristicas']) && !empty($_POST['caracteristicas'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['ip_equipo']) && !empty($_POST['ip_equipo'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['mac_equipo']) && !empty($_POST['mac_equipo'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_tipo']) && !empty($_POST['id_tipo'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_estado']) && !empty($_POST['id_estado'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_estatus']) && !empty($_POST['id_estatus'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_usuario']) && !empty($_POST['id_usuario'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_ubicacion']) && !empty($_POST['id_ubicacion'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_departamento']) && !empty($_POST['id_departamento']))){


    $serialEquipo = $_POST['serial'];
    $marcaEquipo = $_POST['marca'];
    $modeloEquipo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $caracteristicasEquipo = $_POST['caracteristicas'];
    $ip_equipoEquipo = $_POST['ip_equipo'];
    $mac_equipoEquipo = $_POST['mac_equipo'];
    $id_tipoEquipo = $_POST['id_tipo'];
    $id_estadoEquipo = $_POST['id_estado'];
    $id_estatusEquipo = $_POST['id_estatus'];
    $id_usuarioEquipo = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $id_ubicacionEquipo = $_POST['id_ubicacion'];
    $id_departamentoEquipo = $_POST['id_departamento'];




    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO equipos (serial, marca, modelo, caracteristicas, ip_equipo, mac_equipo, id_tipo, id_estado, id_estatus, id_usuario, id_ubicacion, id_departamento)
        values ('$serialEquipo','$marcaEquipo','$modeloEquipo','$caracteristicasEquipo','$ip_equipoEquipo','$mac_equipoEquipo','$id_tipoEquipo','$id_estadoEquipo','$id_estatusEquipo','$id_usuarioEquipo','$id_ubicacionEquipo','$id_departamentoEquipo')")) {


     $serialEquipo = $_POST['serial'];
    $marcaEquipo = $_POST['marca'];
    $modeloEquipo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $caracteristicasEquipo = $_POST['caracteristicas'];
    $ip_equipoEquipo = $_POST['ip_equipo'];
    $mac_equipoEquipo = $_POST['mac_equipo'];
    $id_tipoEquipo = $_POST['id_tipo'];
    $id_estadoEquipo = $_POST['id_estado'];
    $id_estatusEquipo = $_POST['id_estado'];
    $id_usuarioEquipo = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $id_ubicacionEquipo = $_POST['id_ubicacion'];
    $id_departamentoEquipo = $_POST['id_departamento'];


         if($stmt->execute())
        {       
             echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
        }
                 else
                 {
                     '<script>alert("Error al ingresar")</script> ';
             }

        }
}
?>
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Qué quiere decir *no me sale un if para avisarme cuando se estén o intenten duplicar registros por el campo serial*? ¿Dónde debería ocurrir eso? ¿Qué ocurre en lugar de lo esperado? ¿Qué hace tu programa?

Comment: A. Cedano respondiendo a tus preguntas    ¿Qué quiere decir no me sale un if para avisarme cuando se estén o intenten duplicar registros por el campo serial? He realizado diferentes ejercicios con una condicion IF pero no logro que me salga correctamente .      ¿Dónde debería ocurrir eso?  Deberia ocurrir en el insert into ya que ahi es donde tiene que validar si ya esta registrado ese equipo con ese serial    ¿Qué ocurre en lugar de lo esperado?  Inserta todos los datos no importando si el campo serial ya esta registrado en mi BD

Comment: Pero, a qué te refieres, a los `isset` o al `if` del `prepare`, el cual está mal... o sea, el `prepare` es erróneo, esta función es precisamente para evitar pasar los valores junto con la consulta, cada variable debe ser cambiada por un signo de `?`, y pasar las variables aparte en el `bind_param`. Así: `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO equipos (serial, marca, modelo, caracteristicas, ip_equipo, mac_equipo, id_tipo, id_estado, id_estatus, id_usuario, id_ubicacion, id_departamento)
  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {`  ... y luego usas `bind_param`  para pasar cada variable.

Comment: Sobre lo dicho anteriormente, revisa [`bind_param` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Y en cuanto a lo otro, si lo que no te funciona son los `isset`, has una revisión de tu variable POST, para ver lo que hay en ella: `var_dump($_POST);` así podrás revisar si tiene todas las claves que estás evaluando en los `isset`.

Comment: A. Cedano Gracias por responder, creo que no quedo clara mi pregunta ya que no me refiero a que no pasan mis valores pues se inserta correctamente, lo único que necesito es que haga una VALIDACIÓN (CONDICIÓN IF) a la hora de insertar si ya existe ese registro en mi BD con el campo SERIAL

Comment: Sí, la pregunta no es clara. Pero eso no quiere decir que lo que te he dicho sobre `prepare` ... `bind_param` no sea importante. Si dejas el código así, será vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. En cuanto a controlar el duplicado, primeramente tendrías que declarar `serial` como `UNIQUE` en tu base de datos y luego, antes de la inserción puedes crear una función que te verifique mediante un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipos WHERE serial=?;` le pasas el valor a verificar a esa función, ejecutas la consulta en la BD y devuelves `TRUE` o `FALSE` según exista o no y dependiendo de eso insertas o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu campo `serial` no es la clave primaria de la tabla o no es un campo único entonces lo primero que debes hacer es incluir el campo como clave primaria (`PRIMARY KEY`) o clave única (`UNIQUE`) mediante la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE equipos
  ADD UNIQUE (serial);
```

Una vez que hagas eso el servidor MySQL te dará un [error 1062 (`SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_ENTRY)`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) cuando intentes introducir un registro duplicado, no tendrás que realizar consultas previas sensibles a condiciones de carrera que te puedan dar registros duplicados.

El código que he usado para reproducir tu problema ha sido:

```
<?php
/* a) No necesitas los paréntesis en una construcción del lenguaje.
   b) Es mejor usar "require_once" para evitar inclusión doble. */
require_once 'connect_db.php';
/* a) Usar "empty" e "isset" al mismo tiempo es innecesario.
   b) Según PSR-2 sólo debe haber un elemento por línea, evita poner dos. */
if (
    false === empty($_POST['serial'])
    && false === empty($_POST['marca'])
    && false === empty($_POST['modelo'])
    && false === empty($_POST['caracteristicas'])
    && false === empty($_POST['ip_equipo'])
    && false === empty($_POST['mac_equipo'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_tipo'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_estado'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_estatus'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_usuario'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_ubicacion'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_departamento'])
) {
    /* Preparamos la consulta usando ? para insertar los valores */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        INSERT INTO equipos (
            serial,
            marca,
            modelo,
            caracteristicas,
            ip_equipo,
            mac_equipo,
            id_tipo,
            id_estado,
            id_estatus,
            id_usuario,
            id_ubicacion,
            id_departamento
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )
    ");
    /* Comprobamos si hubo problemas con la preparación de la consulta */
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die($mysqli->error);
    }
    /* Asignamos las variables, no es necesario crear variables intermedias */
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss',
        $_POST['serial'],
        $_POST['marca'],
        $_POST['modelo'],
        $_POST['caracteristicas'],
        $_POST['ip_equipo'],
        $_POST['mac_equipo'],
        $_POST['id_tipo'],
        $_POST['id_estado'],
        $_POST['id_estatus'],
        $_POST['id_usuario'],
        $_POST['id_ubicacion'],
        $_POST['id_departamento']
    );
    /* Comprobamos si se pudo realizar la consulta */
    if($stmt->execute() === true) {
        $mensaje = "Registro agregado correctamente";
    } else {
        /* Comprobamos si hubo duplicidad de registro (clave duplicada) */
        if ($stmt->errno === 1062) {
            $mensaje = "Error:\nRegistro duplicado";
        } else {
            $mensaje = "Error al ingresar:\n" . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
    /* Enviamos al navegador de manera segura el mensaje de texto */
    echo '<script>alert(', json_encode($mensaje), ')</script>';
}
/* Mostramos el formulario para introducir datos */
?><form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    serial: <input type="text" name="serial" /><br/>
    marca: <input type="text" name="marca" /><br/>
    modelo: <input type="text" name="modelo" /><br/>
    caracteristicas: <input type="text" name="caracteristicas" /><br/>
    ip_equipo: <input type="text" name="ip_equipo" /><br/>
    mac_equipo: <input type="text" name="mac_equipo" /><br/>
    id_tipo: <input type="text" name="id_tipo" /><br/>
    id_estado: <input type="text" name="id_estado" /><br/>
    id_estatus: <input type="text" name="id_estatus" /><br/>
    id_usuario: <input type="text" name="id_usuario" /><br/>
    id_ubicacion: <input type="text" name="id_ubicacion" /><br/>
    id_departamento: <input type="text" name="id_departamento" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Nota: He usado este esquema (usando el campo `serial` como clave primaria):

```
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
 `serial` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `marca` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `modelo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `caracteristicas` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `ip_equipo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `mac_equipo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_tipo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_estado` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_estatus` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_usuario` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_ubicacion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `id_departamento` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`serial`)
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que necesitaba y si efectivamente mi campo serial no era primario pero lo declare unico

Comment: una pregunta... si quiero hacer lo mismo pero esta vez lo quiero hacer que compare fechas y ID es factible?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de comparaciones?

Comment: Basicamente funciona como una bitacora de equipos de prestamo, el problema que tengo ahi es que no tengo campos para hacerlos unicos y hacer la comparacion si existe en mi BD, solo seria fechas, horas y un campo que se llama descripcion, pero no se con que campo seria factible compararlo y que me mande el error de que ya esta insertado

Comment: Recuerda que una clave única no tiene que estar formada únicamente por un campo, puede ser el conjunto de varios. También tienes la opción de crear un trigger que compruebe la validez antes de la inserción. Si puedes crear una nueva pregunta dando tantos detalles como sea posible de lo que quieres hacer trataré de darte opciones. Déjame el enlace a la nueva pregunta aquí cuando la redactes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, te dejo el enlace cuando este redactada mi pregunta

Comment: Replantere mi pregunta y el problema ya que no es factible como lo pensaba hacer, lo haré al siguiente día de  ya que el cansancio ya hace de las suyas, espero contar con tu ayuda te dejare el link en cuanto realice los cambio y redacte mi pregunta. Saludos y de nuevo gracias

Comment: Sin problema, tómate tu tiempo y descansa. Cuenta conmigo para la siguiente pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de hacer la inserción del valor debes hacer otra consulta que te devuelva (o no) un registro como el que intentas insertar. Ahora, debes elegir cual(es) de los campos de la tabla `equipos` te va(n) a servir para hacer la comparación. Lo ideal es que lo compares con un valor que sepas que es único, así, la consulta solo te devolverá un único registro en caso de que exista, o puedes hacer la comparación contra varios valores, más o menos así:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE marca = ? && modelo = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $marcaEquipo, $modeloEquipo);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->fetch();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // El registro existe
            // Mostrar un error al usuario
        } else {
            // El registro no existe
            // Ejecutar el INSERT INTO
    }
}
```

Probablemente hay alguna consulta más óptima, no obstante, creo que para tu necesidad, esto te servirá.

Comment: Esta forma de solucionar el problema sufre de problemas de [condición de carrera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condición_de_carrera) que podría provocar la existencia de registros duplicados si no se gestiona correctamente mediante el uso de claves únicas o transacciones.

Comment: Mal implementado, si, por eso le he recomendado elegir que campos le van a servir para la comparación, y que lo ideal es que use un valor que sea único. La idea de responder a una pregunta no es necesariamente darle una solución para que haga copy/paste, sino que también es válida una respuesta que le ayude a deducir una solución a su problema. Esta es perfectamente válida.